# rf call within Caret package in r long execution time

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I have a dataframe of 38K rows with 3 columns that I am feeding into a random forest process within caret, the first two columns are character classes and the third column (two one I am trying to explain is a factor). 
Here are the tuning parameters I used for the function call:

```
trControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=1, repeats=1)

rf_model <- train(YVar~., data=training, method="rf", trainControl = trControl, tuneLength = 1)
```

The model takes an extremely long time to run … I cancelled after about 8 hours… a comparable model in Python ran in a few minutes. I think it is something I am doing with the tuning parameters; I've done some research and people who have had a similar issue focused on reducing the number of cross validations/repeats.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data frame? `dput(df[sample(1:nrow(df), 20),])` and paste it here. Did you try just running `randomForrest` without `caret` on the data?

Comment: instead of using `method = 'rf'`, try using `method = 'ranger'`. That should spead things up a bit. Otherwise we need a reproducible example.